# Accessing MSMQ via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, msmq, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed the MSMQ feature onto both server (win 2008 R2) and client machine (win 7) using the following [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967729.aspx). The Feature appears in the server manager and I am able to create a public or privet queue through the GUI. But when I come to try access the queue locally on the server through PowerShell (2.0) none of the [Cmdlet's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh405007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for MSMQ are recognized within the shell.

Are there any further steps that I need to take to access MSMQ through PowerShell? Is there a MSMQ module that I need to load?

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error is the standard unrecognized cmdlet: `The term 'Get-MsmqQueue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click up one level in the link you provided you'll see that you're looking at pre-release PowerShell 4.0 module documentation.  Here's the link to the parent page.

https://web.archive.org/web/20131029215718/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249523.aspx

PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX) has some cmdlets for working with MSMQ, and it works with PowerShell 2.0, though.

Comment: arr I see what I have done now, I have found the correct syntax's thanks.

Comment: Actually, Mike, _your_ link is for pre-release 4.0, but Richard's link is clearly for PowerShell 3--but _only_ for Win Server 2012 and Win 8, hence his issue... which happens to be my issue as well, as posted [here](ttp://serverfault.com/q/534991/14413).

Comment: I don't see PowerShell versions on either of those pages, which makes me think that they were updated since the original answer.

Comment: "up one level in the link" ? where? http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1436237816.png

Answer (score 4):

The below method works in Powershell 2.0:

```
$query = "SELECT MessagesinQueue FROM Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue WHERE Name = 'myPrivateQueueName'"
$wmiObject = Get-WmiObject -Query $query
$wmiObject.MessagesinQueue
```

You can list the queues with this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue"
```

Look at the __PATH property which will end in .Name="theQueueName"

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, i had this error, but with version 5 in windows serveur 2019. I went to check Computer managment, Services and Applications, and there was not a section names Message Queuing. Which would explain why i cannot run the command line.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/installing-message-queuing-msmq

i had to restart my computer after that. A pop up tells you to do so.