# Powershell: can't access MSMQ Cmdlets

Tags: powershell, msmq

I'd like to use the Message Queueing (MSMQ) Cmdlets [Message Queueing (MSMQ) Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn391735%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) but they all show as unavailable:

```
PS C:\users\admin\Desktop> Get-MsmqQueue
Get-MsmqQueue : The term 'Get-MsmqQueue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MsmqQueue
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Get-MsmqQueue:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have Windows 8.1 and PowerShell 4 running as administrator

```
PS C:\users\admin\Desktop> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

Comment: possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17593418/2777098

Comment: The link on that page (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249523.aspx) says: This topic lists the Windows PowerShell® modules included with Windows Server® 2012 R2 and Windows® 8.1. And it says Msmq is one of them. I have Windows 8.1 and the PowerShell 4

Comment: `appwiz.cpl` -> install the msmq server feature.

Comment: Thanks Mathias -- I just assumed the machine I was on had MSMQ already but it turned out it didn't.

Comment: Please add a formal answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to OP's comment, MSMQ features were not installed :

```
I just assumed the machine I was on had MSMQ already but it turned out it didn't.
```

See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/554462/is-it-possible-to-enable-msmq-from-powershell-on-windows-8) for instructions on how to install them with PowerShell